# How to decrypt xxtea encrypt lua file from cocos2D game

Tags: ida, decryption

I'm trying to decipher [this game](https://cdn.redfoxnetwork.net/OPMVNFinal.apk) because it's about to be discontinued

I tried to decompile the apk looking for image resources and lua files. Looking at the received title I guess that the game was encrypted using the xxtea algorithm.

I searched and found that my case is the same as in [this article](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/decrypting-lua-files/21766#21766). I followed and received the decryption key "D2 22 82 7F E9 D3 72 A5 24 90 8C 6D A 96 CB A3". However I can't decrypt the file, I don't know what I've missed, it's all almost right in front of my eyes. but then cannot decrypt.

Please help me decrypt the lua file or at least pls help me get the key to decrypt it, I really need it.

Comment: Is it the same game as your question [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30780/how-to-encode-file)?

Comment: @user7290573 This is another game with advanced encryption